# Can I use GLS for independent data?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, independence, generalized-least-squares, lme4-nlme

I have a continuous variable that is related to a covariable linearly. I need to compare this relationship between months (24 months), but the dataset is very heterogeneous: the sample size is different (very) between months and the covariate range is also different between months, obviously there is a big heteroscedasticity.

I was told that I may use `gls` instead of `lm` because `gls` (in nlme package for R) are specially robust in the absence of homoscedasticity. The variance of my data is not structured and the observations are independent. I am not sure if I can use `gls` anyway or if it is a good idea. I have been looking in books (Pinheiro & Bates, 2002) and other forums but it seems that nobody has tried to do so.

**Is it correct to use `gls` anyway in these cases?**

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the data is independent"?

Comment: I would recommend using ols with heteroskedastic robust standard errors as with gls you need to specify an error structure

Comment: I meant that the observations are independent ie I don't need mixed models